# R - Help translating cURL statement into R httr

Tags: r, httr

Thank you in advance for helping with my first stack overflow request.

I am working with an API through Catapult Sport. I am able to get the following statement to work in my REST Client, I'm currently using Insomnia. I removed the generated access token in this example. Could some help translate the following statement?

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://connect-us.catapultsports.com/api/v4/stats \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
   --data '{"filters": [{"name": "activity_id", "comparison": "=", "values": ["c33392e2-dba7-494b-a045-e3ffa3d1c9c8"]}], "parameters": ["total_player_load", "total_duration", "average_player_load", "explosive_efforts"],"group_by": ["athlete"]}'
```

I keep getting a 400 error using variations of the following R code

```
base_url <- 'https://connect-us.catapultsports.com/api/v4'
filter <- '{"filters": [{"name": "activity_id", "comparison": "=", "values": ["c33392e2-dba7-494b-a045-e3ffa3d1c9c8"]}], "parameters": ["total_player_load", "average_player_load", "explosive_efforts"],"group_by": ["period", "athlete"]}'

r <- POST(url = paste0(base_url,"/stats"), 
                 add_headers(`authorization: Bearer` = access_token),
                 query = list(`data` = filter),
                 verbose()
        )
http_status(r)
content(r, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% fromJSON(flatten=TRUE) %>% as_tibble()
```

Comment: Try `add_headers("authorization" = paste("Bearer", access_token))` and also use `body =` rather than `query =` for the POST request.

Comment: r <- POST(url = paste0(base_url,"/stats"), 
                 add_headers(authorization = paste0("Bearer ",access_token)),
                 body = filter,
                 verbose()
        )

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!